# How to loop through nested array in vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, vue.js

I have array with few multi dimensional array.

my api response

```
0:  name : "name",
    address : "address"

        0:
            reciepts : 
                ballance : 10,
                bill : 101, 
        1:  
            reciepts : 
                ballance : 12,
                bill : 101, 

1:  name : "name",
    address : "address"

        0:
            reciepts : 
                ballance : 13,
                bill : 101, 
        1:
            reciepts : 
                ballance : 14,
                bill : 101, 
2:  name : "name",
    address : "address"

        0:
            reciepts : 
                ballance : 15,
                bill : 101, 
        1:
            reciepts : 
                ballance : 16,
                bill : 101,
```

I am binding this data to a array.

```
this.reportResults=response.data;
```

in the code i am lopping throgh this array like

```
<ul>
            <li v-for="report in reportResults"> // this woks fine
                <div class="row " style="background-color: #f4fbee;">
                    <div class="col-md-2">{{report.bill_no}}</div>
                </div>
           </li>
</ul>
```

but here i want to loop throgh the reciepts. so i just wrote

```
<ul>
                <li v-for="report in reportResults"> // this woks fine
                    <div class="row " style="background-color: #f4fbee;">
                        <div class="col-md-2">{{report.bill_no}}</div>
                    </div>
                   <div class="row" v-for="reciepts in report"> // this print nothing
                       {{reciepts.bill}}
                    </div>
               </li>
    </ul>
```

inner loop prints nothing. But if i print raw data inside my second loop like {{reciepts}} it prints all the data. so how can i loop through the reciepts object?

Comment: The data structure in your question sample is a bit confusing. Is `receipts` the key value for the array or is it just an array that has objects that have `receipts` keys?

Could you post the response data as JSON?

Comment: i am facing issue with inner loop. i want to display all the data of receipts array. not through bill_no

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/48hjacmk/

Comment: @ChrisG it print nothing

Comment: Can you paste JSON data like a normal string?

Comment: @ChrisG https://ibb.co/fsxTTd

Comment: What @ChrisG wrote should work, but he didn't copy your misspelling of the word `reciepts` :)

Comment: ok sure . i wil make format

Comment: My guess is you need `v-for="reciepts in report.reciepts"`

Answer (score 1):

@Chris G already posted the answer in the comments. However, since it's hidden a bit, here's the answer:

```
<div class="row" v-for="reciept in report.reciepts">{{reciept.bill}}</div>
```

Note that I have removed the plural of reciept when accessing a single property.